# What are lockups and lockdowns in chord progressions?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions

I've been watching this video from 8-bit music theory

and he mentioned lockups and lockdowns in chord progressions (at [4:17](https://youtu.be/BNH2pKfvyPQ?t=257)). What does that mean?

Comment: At what time in the video are these mentioned?

Comment: @topomorto [4:17](https://youtu.be/BNH2pKfvyPQ?t=257)

Comment: All you game composers out there, want to know something?  I invariably turn sound OFF when playing.  Those repetitive ditties get SO annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it sounds like the speaker may be saying "lockup" and "lockdown," he is actually saying "walk up" and "walk down."  The chord progressions are "walking up" when they seem to ascend melodically, and "walking down" when they seem to descend melodically.

This "walk up/down" terminology refers to a root motion that ascends or descends a scale by step, rather than by leaps (thanks @user452665).

Comment: To be more specific, usually this "walk up/down" terminology refers to a root motion that ascends or descends a scale by step, rather than by leap. +1

Comment: @user45266 That's a very good comment.  I've added it to the answer; I hope that's OK.